# fat free: how to specify a query string in route

Tags: fat-free-framework

In Fat Free Framework, I am trying to figure out how to specify a query string  in the route call or the routes.ini file.

I want to be able to decode a route specified like this

http://example.com/search?category=22&term=wide

Note if possible I'd like to have a varying number of elements in the query string.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The framework doesn't allow to route query strings, only paths.

So, either you modify your routes to include the parameters in the URI path:

```
;routes.ini
GET /search/@category = MyController->searchByCategory
GET /search/@category/@term = MyController->searchByCategoryAndTerm
```

(which requires a strict order of the parameters)

Or you route everything to one same controller and parse the query string there:

```
;routes.ini
GET /search = MyController->search
```

```
class MyController {

  function search(\Base $f3) {
    $category=$f3->get('GET.category);
    $term=$f3->get('GET.term');
    //etc.
  }

}
```

If you're implementing a search form, the second solution looks the most appropriate.

Comment: I agree that the second form is more appropriate, but how should I write the route in the routes.ini; this is where I fall short. Should it be something like GET /search/* ?

Comment: In case it can be useful to someone else a simple GET /search route plus the manual decoding as suggested does the job. Perfect thanks

Comment: `GET /search` is enough. The query string doesn't need to appear in the routing definition. I've updated the answer.